# How to pass ViewModel property as model to partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have ViewModel called LogViewModel in wich i have 3 properties as shown below.

```
public class LogViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Log> Logs { get; private set; }
    public PaginationHelper Pagination { get; set; }
    public LogFilter Filter { get; set; }
}
```

LogViewModel is passed to View as Model.
Now i need to pass LogFilter (with data) to partial view like:

```
@Html.Partial("_LogsFilter", Model.Filter)
```

I tried a lot of methods but always get the same error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'Infrastructure.Presentation.Desk.ViewModels.LogViewModel',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'Infrastructure.Presentation.Desk.Models.LogFilter'.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your `Filter` property is probably null. Try something like `@Html.Partial("_LogsFilter", Model.Filter ?? new LogFilter())`, of course if `LogFilter` has a default constructor.

Comment: Is your view's `ModelType` declaration `@model LogFilter` instead of `@model LogViewModel`?

Comment: @Zabavsky thanks that worked. I was creating a new instance of LogFilter in LogViewModel constructor and after that accidentally had setted its value to null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `Filter` property is null, the framework will pass the model from the parent view to the partial, which is `LogViewModel`, while partial view is expecting type of `LogFilter`.

To prevent this assure that `Filter` property is instantiated before rendering the view, or do something like this:

```
@Html.Partial("_LogsFilter", Model.Filter ?? new LogFilter())
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case your partial view should expect "**LogFilter**" as model. But I think you are passing **LogFilter** and partial view expects "**LogViewModel**" . Please rectify the mismatch.

Comment: In my _LogFilter.cshtml partial view model is defined as LogFilter althought this also could case this error.