# MVC Passing model property to renderpartial failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I have a model

```
public class test
{
    private List<int> _abc;

    public List<int> abc
    {
        get { return _abc; }
        set { _abc = value; }
    }
}
```

My partial page:

```
@model List<int>

//do something with model
```

My main page :

```
@model somenamespace.test

@Html.Partial("~/Views/Test/partial.cshtml", model.abc)
```

But I got this error when trying to access the page :

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type , but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]'.

I'm confused because my partial view accept list of integer and I pass property with list of integer as datatype, anything wrong with my code?

Any help will be appreciated and sorry for bad english.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass ViewModel property as model to partial view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949949/how-to-pass-viewmodel-property-as-model-to-partial-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property `abc` is `null`, and by default the `test` model is then passed to the partial, resulting in the error. Ensure you initialize `abc` in the controller, or in a parameterless constructor for `test`

For example

```
public class test
{
  public test()
  {
    abc = new List<int>();
  }
  public List<int> abc { get; set; }
}
```